# Can you use the dig method to get the last element of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

Lets say I have the following:

```
nested_object = [0, 1, 2, {foo: 'bar'}]
```

How do I use dig to select the last element of the array as I search for deeper nested objects?

Comment: Thank you naomik for the grammar corrections :)

Answer (score 10):

A negative value integer in any dig method arguments starts at the end of the array and moves towards the beginning.  So `-1` selects the last element of the array, `-2` selects the second from last, and so on.  So, in your case:

```
target = nested_object.dig(-1, :foo)
```

will select the last element of the array and proceed from there.

Comment: what is? You create question and answer on it, or?

Comment: @AlexGolubenko that is [perfectly fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

Comment: @AlexGolubenko I am just trying to help others looking for answers to questions I couldn't find on Stack Overflow.  If I couldn't find the answer, I would have left the question for others to answer.  Thanks.